# Unbound using internal DNS for AmazonAWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I have a dedicated DNS server in my internal network that relies on OpenDNS for the major requests. But when I try to get the IP for AWS-related services (like a Load Balancer) I can't get the values : the DNS server returns no values.

Here's my current Unboud configuration file:

```
server:
    verbosity: 1
    use-syslog: yes
    logfile: "/var/log/unbound/unbound.log"
    log-time-ascii: yes

    do-ip4: yes
    do-ip6: yes
    do-udp: yes
    do-tcp: yes

    interface: 0.0.0.0
    interface: ::0

    # Allow local machine
    access-control: 127.0.0.0/8 allow
    access-control: 172.31.0.0/16 allow

    # Disallow everything else
    access-control: 0.0.0.0/0 refuse

    # use all CPUs
    num-threads: 2

    # power of 2 close to num-threads  
    msg-cache-slabs: 16
    rrset-cache-slabs: 16
    infra-cache-slabs: 16
    key-cache-slabs: 16

    # Read the root hints from this file
    root-hints: "/var/lib/unbound/root.hints"

    harden-referral-path: no
    use-caps-for-id: no
    hide-identity: yes
    hide-version: yes
    harden-glue: yes
    harden-dnssec-stripped: yes
    qname-minimisation: yes

    # the time to live (TTL) value lower bound, in seconds. Default 0.
    # If more than an hour could easily give trouble due to stale data.
    # WARNING : against protocol rule but efficient against stupidly too low TTLs
    cache-min-ttl: 1800 # 30 minutes

    # the time to live (TTL) value cap for RRsets and messages in the
    # cache. Items are not cached for longer. In seconds.
    cache-max-ttl: 3600 # 60 minutes

    prefetch: yes

    # If nonzero, unwanted replies are not only reported in statistics, but also
    # a running total is kept per thread. If it reaches the threshold, a warning
    # is printed and a defensive action is taken, the cache is cleared to flush
    # potential poison out of it.  A suggested value is 10000000, the default is
    # 0 (turned off). We think 10K is a good value.
    unwanted-reply-threshold: 10000

    # Should additional section of secure message also be kept clean of unsecure
    # data. Useful to shield the users of this validator from potential bogus
    # data in the additional section. All unsigned data in the additional section
    # is removed from secure messages.
    val-clean-additional: yes

    # Log validation failures
    val-log-level: 2

    private-address: 192.168.0.0/16
    private-address: 172.16.0.0/16
    private-address: 10.0.0.0/8
    private-address: 172.31.0.0/16

    # Optimise
    # https://unbound.net/documentation/howto_optimise.html

    # Faster UDP with multithreading (only on Linux).
    so-reuseport: yes

    # Cache size
    rrset-cache-size: 100m
    msg-cache-size: 50m

    # DNSSEC managment
    harden-below-nxdomain: yes
    harden-dnssec-stripped: yes

forward-zone:
    name: "amazonaws.com"
    forward-addr: 172.31.0.2

forward-zone:
# OpenDNS
    name: "."
    forward-addr: 208.67.222.222
    forward-addr: 208.67.220.220
    forward-addr: 2620:119:35::35
    forward-addr: 2620:119:53::53
```

I then did a `unbound-control flush amazonaws.com` and tested with

`unbound-control lookup some-load-balancer.elb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com`

And got the following result:

```
The following name servers are used for lookup of some-load-balancer.elb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com.
forwarding request:
Delegation with 0 names, of which 0 can be examined to query further addresses.
It provides 1 IP addresses.
172.31.0.2          rto 13 msec, ttl 493, ping 1 var 3 rtt 50, tA 0, tAAAA 0, tother 0, EDNS 0 probed.
```

And dig returns no results:

```
@> dig A some-load-balancer.elb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com @127.0.0.1

; <<>> DiG 9.16.42-Debian <<>> A some-load-balancer.elb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com @127.0.0.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44316
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;some-load-balancer.elb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com. IN A

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul 11 13:35:35 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 104
```

While querying directly the AWS DNS server :

```
@> dig A some-load-balancer.elb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com @172.31.0.2

; <<>> DiG 9.16.42-Debian <<>> A some-load-balancer.elb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com @172.31.0.2
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15642
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;some-load-balancer.elb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
some-load-balancer.elb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com. 26  IN A 172.31.1.1
some-load-balancer.elb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com. 26  IN A 172.31.2.2
some-load-balancer.elb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com. 26  IN A 172.31.3.3

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 172.31.0.2#53(172.31.0.2)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul 11 13:36:14 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 152
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably a better question for ServerFault.